# Sort alphanumeric string containing decimal in C#, issue with decimal points

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq, sorting

The problem is that the below list contains alphanumeric data, and also it has data like 6.1 and 6.10 which is same in terms of integer but not same as a string.

**Problem List**

```
 6.1
 6.10
 6.11
 6.12
 6.2
 6.3
 6.4 - a
 6.4 - b
 6.5
 6.6
 6.7
 6.8
 6.9
```

**Expected List**

```
6.1
6.2
6.3
6.4 - a
6.4 - b
6.5
6.6
6.7
6.8
6.9
6.10
6.11
6.12
```

**Code**

```
 var sortedData = ViolationCodesList.OrderBy(x => x.SubCategory).ToList();
```

> Note : SubCategory is string ..

Comment: You have to convert every string into a decimal in order to sort by it. Or is this actually a list of versions? In this case you may use the `Version`-class instead of decimal and order by that.

Comment: One of the problems if you store multiple informations in a single (string) property. You can use the `Version` class as already mentioned and for the `a` and `b` another property

Comment: @Richard , please look at the query.  The link you marked duplicate has a different issue than mine.

Comment: No, the underlying issue is mixing numeric and non-numeric data in a single string. And the solution is the same: separate out the different parts when comparing (or pre-process to extract the search keys).

Comment: @Danish Try the solution to that question before you say it's not the same: `var sortedData = ViolationCodesList.OrderBy(x => PadNumbers(x.SubCategory)).ToList();`